# CSS Floating Footer

Tags: css, footer

I want to make a footer that stays at the bottom of the viewable window UNLESS it butts up against the content when you resize the window smaller.

I tried...
bottom:0;
position:absolute;
...but the footer gets in the way when the window is smaller.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this will do what you want: [CSS layout: 100% height with header and footer](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/examples/csslayout1.html). I've used it on a site and it can be tricky to implement depending on the complexity of your existing layout.

Answer (score 0):

I use the method as described by The Man In Blue called [footerStickAlt](http://www.themaninblue.com/writing/perspective/2005/08/29/) - works a charm, CSS won't validate if you include the IE6 hack though.